# php template code - all properties page display issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, properties

My page: http://kevinkang.ca/en_US/all-properties/ was broken yesterday. 
But I can't find any problem on these. Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

```
<div class="grid-x all-properties-page">
        <?php  
      $args = array( 'category__not_in' => array( 4, 8, 9, 10  ) , 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while (  $loop->have_posts() ) :  $loop->the_post(); ?>
         <?php $i=0; ?>
             <div class="medium-12 cell padding-top-page">
              <div class="home-data description-title-price">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                      <div class="grid-x">
                        <div class="medium-6 cell">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="medium-6 cell text-right">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('price'); ?></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="grid-x">
            <ul class="images3">
            <?php
              //Get the images ids from the post_metadata
              $images = acf_photo_gallery('3-images', $post->ID);
              $img3=0;
              if( count($images) ):
                  //Cool, we got some data so now let's loop over it
                  foreach($images as $image):
                      $id = $image['id']; // The attachment id of the media
                      $title = $image['title']; //The title
                      $caption= $image['caption']; //The caption
                      $full_image_url= $image['full_image_url']; //Full size image url
                      $full_image_url = acf_photo_gallery_resize_image($full_image_url, 1562, 760); //Resized size to 262px width by 160px height image url
                      $thumbnail_image_url= $image['thumbnail_image_url']; //Get the thumbnail size image url 150px by 150px
                      $url= $image['url']; //Goto any link when clicked
                      $target= $image['target']; //Open normal or new tab
                      $alt = get_field('photo_gallery_alt', $id); //Get the alt which is a extra field (See below how to add extra fields)
                      $class = get_field('photo_gallery_class', $id); 
                      $img3++;
          ?>

                  <?php if( !empty($url) ){ ?><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" <?php echo ($target == 'true' )? 'target="_blank"': ''; ?>><?php } ?>
                <li style="background-image: url(<?php echo $full_image_url; ?>);" class="img-list<?php echo $img3; ?>">      
                <?php if( !empty($url) ){ ?></a><?php } ?></li>

          <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

          </ul>
                <?php foreach ( get_the_category() as $value) {
                     $i++; ?> <h3 class="cat<?php echo $i; ?> <?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name;} ?></h3>
              </div></a>
              <div class="grid-container pr-address-bg">
                <div class="address-cont price-address">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_field('price'); ?></a>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_field('address_first_line'); ?></a>   
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>


        </div>
```

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/) -- Do `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` and [edit] your question to incorporate the result.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a lot of problems in your HTML ( inside , multiple  tags. First check your HTML with https://validator.w3.org/. It looks the main parts of the problems come from header.php. I would have a look.

Comment: sorry the html was stripped in my comment. I mean div inside h1 ...)